# What length should be the gap to block UV waves from the Sun?

Tags: waves, home-experiment, sun

The origin of the question is practical, but the theoretical part is interesting too.

Let's rest a little bit on the roof on a sunny summer day. We don't want to get burned, so we usually place some cloth in between the Sun and our skin: an umbrella or a canopy.

Given the length of the wave, how to calculate the minimum and the maximum length of the gaps (within cloth) and the distance from the cloth to a detector (human skin) such that waves get blocked or absorbed and doesn't make a significant trace on a detector?

I may miss some details - the comments are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

The gaps just need to be smaller than the wavelength of the UV radiation. Waves can only pass through gaps larger than their wavelength. In symbols $$ L < \lambda $$

Where $ L $ is your gap length, and $ \lambda $ is the wavelegnth of the UV radiation. Typically this from  is $400$ to $10$ nm, with UVA in the $400$ to $320$ nm range, UVB in the $320$ to $290$ nm range, and UVC doesn't even penetrate the atmosphere.